# How to replace all newlines bewtween two HTML tags with Regex in c#

Tags: c#, regex

I have a html code structured like this:

```
<html>
   <body>
      ...
      <p class="class1">
       Text
       Some more text
       Even more text
      </p>
      ...
      <p class="class2">
       Bla
       Bla
       Read more at
      <a href="..." >Link</a>
      </p>
</html>
```

How can I replace all newlines between `<p>` tags with `<br />` in C#? All other tags shouldn't match.

That's the Regex I currently have. But it doesn't work as I expect it to.

`/(?<=<p).*(\n).*(?=<\/p>)/gs`

Comment: What is the expected result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is removing some piece of text between two other pieces of text canbe solved with a regex in C# in the following way:

```cs
var start = @"<p[\s>]";
var end = @"</p>";
var pattern = $@"(?s){start}.*?{end}";
var result = Regex.Replace(text, pattern, m => 
    m.Value.Replace("\n", "<br />"));
```

Here, `(?s)<p[\s>].*?</p>` will find all substrings between `<p` (followed with whitespace or `>`) and `</p>`, and then `m => m.Value.Replace("\n", "<br />")` will replace LF symbols with `<br />` in the match values.

If the linebreaks can be mixed, you will need to use another `Regex.Replace` call, and replace the `m.Value.Replace("\n", "<br />")` with

```cs
Regex.Replace(m.Value, "\r\n?|\n", "<br />")
```

Or, if you plan to shrink consecutive line breaks into a single `<br />`:

```cs
Regex.Replace(m.Value, "(?:\r\n?|\n)+", "<br />")
```